# How to set variable order (not term order) in polynomial ring in sagemath?

Tags: python, sage

I need to create a `PolynomialRing` in sage, with an unknown number of variables `x0,...,xn`. For this I use the following code:

```
R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 'x', 3, order='degrevlex')
R.inject_variables(verbose=False)
```

In this case, `n = 2`. However, I also want `x2` to be considered greater than `x1`.

Instead, I get the following:

```
sage: x1 < x2
False
```

How can I set the *variable order* of my ring to have `x0 < x1 < ... < xn`?

Comment: You might also try asking at ask.sagemath.org and/or the Google group sage-support.